# Display word file by docx-preview.js

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

i was looking for a solution to display the Word file on the HTML page, and I found the following code, and it is exactly what I want.

**The only problem I have is:** You have to upload the Word file here and click on the button to display the file.

That is, I don't want any button to be clicked!

For example, you enter the following link: mysite.com/articles?id=5

I have a table in the database where I saved the address of the Word file, for example ID 5, the following address is saved:

**files/articles/new-method-in-raising-children.docx**

I want to display this in the div tag in the page load.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>display word file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="files" type="file" accept=".docx"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnPreview" value="Preview Word Document" onclick="PreviewWordDoc()"/>
    <div id="word-container" class=""></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/docx-preview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PreviewWordDoc() {
            //Read the Word Document data from the File Upload.
            var doc = document.getElementById("files").files[0];
     
            //If Document not NULL, render it.
            if (doc != null) {
                //Set the Document options.
                var docxOptions = Object.assign(docx.defaultOptions, {
                    useMathMLPolyfill: true
                });
                //Reference the Container DIV.
                var container = document.querySelector("#word-container");
     
                //Render the Word Document.
                docx.renderAsync(doc, container, null, docxOptions);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler and better way for this problem:

https://github.com/mwilliamson/dotnet-mammoth